# Term for spoon and knife combo

Tags: single-word-requests

Lately, some fruit like kiwis have been sold with a spoon and knife combo.

Is there a term for these implements?  I tried looking up *spife* and *knoon* but it came out empty.  All I get is sporks and more sporks.

**Edit** I just looked up spife again: must have type it incorrectly the last time.  It is called a spife.  Wiki says it is called something else but when I looked up that word it was Czech for some female private parts.

Would the plural be spifes or spives?

Comment: "spifes" on https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/spife

Comment: The nutella site http://www.freestufffinder.ca/free-nutella-instant-win-contest-over-21000-prizes-to-won/ also uses spifes

Comment: Since the term "spife" is rarely used, I don't think you'll find a satisfactory and definitive answer.

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend the plural form "spives" keeping in chronology with the latter half of the word knife's plural as "knives".